# partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_unowned

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have the following Swift function:

```
func refresh(optionalHandler: @escaping (() -> Void) = {}) {
  afnetworking.get(someURL, parameters: nil, successHandler: {
    (task: URLSessionDataTask, object: Any) in
      print(task)
      optionalHandler() // This crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
  })
}
```

Not sure what's happening here... the full error is:

```
optionalHandler () -> ()    0x000000010018baac MyApp`partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_unowned @convention(block) () -> () to @callee_owned () -> () at MyViewController.swift
```

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: We need the code for optionalHandler mate

Answer (score 0):

Probably inside in `afnetworking.get(someURL, parameters: nil, successHandler:` you call `successHandler` a few times.

Second call `optionalHandler()` crashes your app